# removeData() jquery method not working

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I think I'm using removeData correctly but it doesn't seem to be working, here's what I'm seeing in the dev console, could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

I'm outputting the current data attribute value, calling removeData, then outputting the value again and its still there.

```
$('.questionList > li').eq(1).data('fieldlength')
3
$('.questionList > li').eq(1).removeData('fieldlength');
[
<li class=​"questionBox" data-createproblem=​"false" data-fieldlength=​"3" data-picklistvalues data-required=​"true" data-sfid=​"a04d000000ZBaM3AAL" data-type=​"Text">​
<div class=​"questionLabel">​Birthdate​</div>​
</li>​
]
$('.questionList > li').eq(1).data('fieldlength')
3
```

Comment: The usage is: `jQuery.removeData($('.questionList > li').eq(1), "fieldlength")`

Comment: @karthikr There's two methods: http://api.jquery.com/removeData/ and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.removeData/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's because your `data` originates in the HTML `data-fieldlength` attribute. According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/):

> When using .removeData("name"), jQuery will attempt to locate a data-
>   attribute on the element if no property by that name is in the
>   internal data cache. To avoid a re-query of the data- attribute, set
>   the name to a value of either null or undefined (e.g. .data("name",
>   undefined)) rather than using .removeData().

So instead of

```
$('.questionList > li').eq(1).removeData('fieldlength');
```

you should do

```
$('.questionList > li').eq(1).data('fieldlength',null);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, though I'm still a little fuzzy on exactly what is going on even after reading the explanation in the docs.

Comment: As I understand it: the `.data()` method checks for a JavaScript value for a value, and if it can't find one, it slurps in the `data-` attribute instead. You removed the internal JavaScript value, so it went to the `data-` attribute like it was designed to. If instead you set the JavaScript value to `null`, it retrieves that happily and ignores the `data-` attribute.

Comment: I used to think that the `data-` attributes were slurped in just once, when the page was first loaded -- and if that were the case, your code would have worked fine. In fact, [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) suggest that approach *was* used prior to jQuery 1.4.3

Comment: It seems, contrary to the quoted documentation above, passing `undefined` has no effect, but passing `null` to the `data()` call sets the value to nothing.

Answer (score 54):

There is bit of gotcha I wanted to clarify in case anyone else stumbles upon it...

If you have HTML5 `data-*` attributes on an element you need to use jQuery's `removeAttr()` instead of `removeData()` if you want to remove them from the element in the DOM.

For example, to actually remove a data attribute from an element you need to use:

```
$({selector}).removeAttr('data-fieldlength');
```

You can *read* values like this with `$({selector}).data('fieldlength')` but `removeData()` doesn't actually remove them if they are HTML attributes on an element present in the source of the page (it just deletes it in memory, so that if you query it again with jQuery it *appears* to have been removed).

Personally I think this behaviour is broken and I'm sure catches a lot of people out.

Comment: I think that it would be better, from a coding perspective, to retain the `data-` attribute in the DOM, but set the JavaScript `.data()` variable to `null`. This gives the desired result in jQuery without destroying the DOM attribute unnecessarily; there's always a possibility it will be used elsewhere (for instance, CSS styles might depend on it).

Comment: @Blazemonger, as a note, I've tried to change `data-remote` from true to false, and using `.data()` or `.removeData()` didn't worked, `.removeAttr()` worked fine. So for those who don't care about the DOM attribute this method works great.

Answer (score 5):

`.removeData()` will **only remove data from jQuery's internal `.data()` cache** so any corresponding `data-` attributes on the element will not be removed. A later call to `data()` will therefore re-retrieve the value from the element's `data-` attribute. To prevent this, use [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) alongside [`.removeData()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/) to remove the `data-` attribute as well.

Example:

```
$('div').removeData('info');
$('div').removeAttr('data-info');
```

Then set either:

```
$('div').data('info', 222);
$('div').attr('data-info', 222);
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually this works better for me. Because it leaves the attribute intact in the element but with no assigned value to it.

```
$(selector).attr("data-fieldlength","");
```

Comment: Spent a bunch of time on this.  I think there is a bug in JQuery.  I ended up using this variant as well  \ $(thisTr).find(".tdTspec").attr("data-tspecno", "0");\

Answer (score 2):

In Hidden Field using custom data attribute to store object data
Should use .removeAttr() instead of .removeData() using ID

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use the DOM's own remove method. Index 0 references the first DOM element in the jQuery result set, so you can make direct DOM calls on it.

```js
console.log($('[data-fieldlength]').data('fieldlength'));
$('[data-fieldlength]')[0].removeAttribute('data-fieldlength');
console.log($('[data-fieldlength]').data('fieldlength'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-fieldlength="42">Hello Elliot</div>
```